# what does "with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(\'__file__')) ,'.\\profile.json') as profile_json)" mean ? python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

what does this line mean ?

Also I'm getting error in this line, The error says :
"unexpected character after line continuation character"

I'm new to this and I'm not able to resolve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

my code -
from ibm_watson import PersonalityInsightsV3

```
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

from os.path import join, dirname

import json

import os

authenticator = 
IAMAuthenticator('{api key')

personality_insights = PersonalityInsightsV3(version='2017-10-13', 
authenticator=authenticator)

personality_insights.set_service_url('{url}')



with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(\'__file__')) 
,'.\\profile.json')) as profile_json)

profile =personality_insights.profile(profile_json.read(),'application/json', 
         content_type='application/json', consumption_preferences=True, 
         raw_scores=True,get_result())

print(json.dumps(profile, indent=2))
```

Comment: Please post your code and the full traceback as formatted code.

Comment: Do you really have a backslash here `os.path.abspath(\'__file__')`?

Comment: Why are you using backslashes with profile.json?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I'm so sorry for that , forgot to add the code. I've added the code to the question

Comment: @nitind My teacher had sent this code to me and asked me to troubleshoot. I really dont know much about the syntax to be honest. I have a question , where am is supposed to keep the profile.json as no specific path has been mentioned in the code.

Comment: Try `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
,'profile.json')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many Python syntax errors in your code it is hard to know where to begin.

So I am giving you a (corrected) sample from the API documentation: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights?code=python#profile

Take a note of the position and inclusion of  `\`, `:`, and indentations. They are key to python syntax.

```py
from ibm_watson import PersonalityInsightsV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from os.path import join, dirname
import json

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
personality_insights = PersonalityInsightsV3(
    version='2017-10-13',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

personality_insights.set_service_url('{url}')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), 'profile.json')) as profile_json:
    profile = personality_insights.profile(
        profile_json.read(),
        'application/json',
        content_type='application/json',
        consumption_preferences=True,
        raw_scores=True
    ).get_result()
    print(json.dumps(profile, indent=2))
```

By the way, by including it in your question you have made your API key public.

When written correctly the line in question means: Open the file, found at this location as the variable `profile_json`, which if successful will be used in the indented code.

```py
dirname(__file__)
```

is the directory location of the python file you are running.

`join`, constructs a platform independent file path. You shouldn't include directory separators because that would defeat the platform independence mantra. So in your case you are expecting the input `profile.json` to be in the same directory as your python code.

Comment: Oh I didn't know people can misuse my API key. am I in trouble ? cause its my teachers API key .

Comment: Just need to add quotes in the - dirname("__file__"). Entire code is working correctly.